# OWLAPI adds redundant AnnotationProperty declaration from import

Tags: owl, owl-api

I have a simple ontology (see the OWL functional syntax below) which imports dcterms.  From dcterms, I have an annotation on a class using the annotation property dcterms:title:

```
AnnotationAssertion(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title> :A "The title of A")
```

Using the OWLAPI, if I create an OWLOntology from my ontology file and then simply save it back to file or print it to the console, then the following annotation property declaration is added to my ontology:

```
Declaration(AnnotationProperty(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title>))
```

Given that dcterms:title is declared in <http://purl.org/dc/terms/title>, which is imported in to my ontology, this is redundant.  Furthermore, it adds an unnecessary OWL construct to my ontology.

Is there someway to prevent OWLAPI from adding that annotation property declaration to my ontology?

Here is the ontology:

```
Prefix(:=<http://www.semanticweb.org/wmilnor/ontologies/2018/0/AnnotationProperties2#>)
Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)


Ontology(<http://www.semanticweb.org/wmilnor/ontologies/2018/0/AnnotationProperties2>
Import(<http://purl.org/dc/terms>)

Declaration(Class(:A))


############################
#   Classes
############################

# Class: :A (:A)

AnnotationAssertion(<http://purl.org/dc/terms/title> :A "The title of A")


)
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is not redundant, since it states that `http://purl.org/dc/terms/title` is an OWL AnnotationProperty, and this isn't said in the document at http://purl.org/dc/terms/, which doesn't "declare" dcterms:title in the OWL sense. The OWL type of the property needs to be declared within the ontology to avoid ambiguity in RDF serializations.

Incidentally, since http://purl.org/dc/terms/ doesn't declare itself to be an owl:Ontology, the semantics of import are a little different from normal OWL imports—the triples are [*included* rather than *imported*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/#Extracting_Declarations_and_the_IRIs_of_the_Directly_Imported_Ontology_Documents) and this may have an impact on where things are declared.